# recompile single class in package

Tags: java

I am running into this problem when trying to recompile a single class inside a package.

Now this class uses global types and some of these global types reference it. So taking it out of the package really isn't an option.

So when I try to compile it with javac alone, I get invalid symbol errors and netbeans shows it is trying to compile things like classespackage.globaltype. Basically it is searching for the global classes inside of the package. Is there anyway to stop it from doing that?

Here is the code:

`Global`

```
public class Global {
    example.Main main;
    public Global(example.Main m) {
        main = m;
    }
}
```

`example.Main`

```
package example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Global g = new Global(new Main()); // COMPILE ERROR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get invalid symbol errors

You probably meant "Cannot find symbol" errors? This can be caused by anything. Imported class which is not in the compiletime classpath, methods which does not exist, variables which are out of the scope. You really need to post the compilation errors to get more detailed answers.

At least, this much sounds like that you didn't specify the dependencies (the imported classes) in the compiletime classpath using the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument.

> Is there anyway to stop it from doing that?

By listening to those errors and taking actions accordingly.

---

**Update** as per the posted code example: the cause of the problem is that classes in the *default* package (i.e. classes *without* a `package` declaration) are **invisible** to classes inside a concrete package (i.e. classes *with* a `package` declaration). You need to put `Global` in a package. Then it's visible (importable) to classes inside a package.

Comment: Do I have to do -cp "the.class"? Because I have -cp "the.jar". And I can recompile any of the global classes fine. It is because it is inside the package that it is looking for the global classes to be in that package.

Comment: You need to specify the package root in the classpath as well. You can do this by adding `.` (dot) to the `-cp`. E.g. `javac -cp .;the.jar com/example/SomeClass.java` (note that the path separator is `;` in Windows and `:` in *nix).

Comment: It still can not find the global symbols.

Comment: Added an example project above.

Comment: So there is no way around not putting the global class in a package?

Comment: No. Packageless classes are invisible to classes inside a package. That's a rule. Just put classes in a package. That's also the normal practice. Packageless classes are only useful as playground/fiddling/startup classes.

Comment: The global classes are in another library though.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the global types in a class package, you'll have to include them in your classpath. When you do javac, make sure you include the global types class in your classpath (with the -cp option.)